# c# events vs List<Func<Args>>

Tags: c#, .net

is there any difference, e.g. less functional or in performance, memory, between using C# `event` vs a `List<Func<MyArgs>>`, the way I understand with an event I would call

```
obj.MyClickEvent += handler;
```

while with the list

```
obj.MyOnClickFuncs.Add(clickFunc);
```

right now the `List<Func<Args>>` method just seems much simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events provide a more restrictive API for code wishing to subscribe to the events:

- They can subscribe
- They can unsubscribe

(In theory the underlying event concept provides a "raise" mechanism as well, but that's not implemented by C# events, and I suspect is effectively obsolete - I suspect because it violates the isolation described in this answer.)

They can't do anything else. For example, this would work with your "just expose a list" approach, but not with an event:

```cs
obj.MyOnClickFuncs.Clear();
```

Likewise with an event, subscribers don't get to call the handlers from other subscribers - whereas they can with the list approach.

In other words, events provide more isolation between subscribers. If you don't care about that isolation, then go ahead and expose a list. Personally I think the isolation is a good thing. There are plenty of things I *don't* like about events, but the isolation provided isn't one of them :)

Comment: so if I make the List private, expose an Add and Remove there would be no difference

Comment: @buga: Indeed - except that anything expecting to use events wouldn't "understand" that this was expected to behave like an event. It would be like avoiding using properties and instead providing `GetXyz` and `SetXyz` methods.